# SQL Syntax error when connecting to MySQL through Java

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, connection

I'm connecting to a database through Java with the following code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Can {

//Database Credentials
private static String userName = "root";
private static String password = "root";
private static String databaseName = "books";

static Connection connection = null; // manages connection
static Statement statement = null; // query statement
static ResultSet resultSet = null; // manages results

static Can can;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    can = new Can();
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;
    int numberOfColumns;


    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+databaseName, userName, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        //creating the tables
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Instructor" + "(instructorID INT, instructorName VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (instructorID))");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Lecture" + "(lectureID INT, lectureName VARCHAR(30), time TIME, credit INT, instructorID INT, PRIMARY KEY (lectureID))");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE LectureStudent" + "(lectureID INT, studentID INT, PRIMARY KEY (lectureID, studentID))");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Student" + "(studentID INT, studentName VARCHAR(30), CGPA FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (studentID))");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Assignment" + "(assignmentID INT, deadline INT(30), lectureID INT, PRIMARY KEY (assignmentID))");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Results" + "(resultID INT, grade FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (resultID)");


        //inserting info. into the tables
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES('1', 'instructorName1')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES('2', 'instructorName2')");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Lecture VALUES('1', 'lectureName1', '20:16:40', '3', '1')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Lecture VALUES('2', 'lectureName2', '20:33:20', '4', '1')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Lecture VALUES('3', 'lectureName3', '20:33:25', '4', '2')");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO LectureStudent VALUES('1', '100')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO LectureStudent VALUES('2', '100')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO LectureStudent VALUES('3', '100')");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Student VALUES('100', 'studentName1', '2.4')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Student VALUES('200', 'studentName2', '2.5')");
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Student VALUES('300', 'studentName3', '2.6')");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Assignment VALUES('1000', '1969-12-31 10:40:00.0', '1')");

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Results VALUES('1', '90.0')");


        //commit the transaction
        connection.commit();

        connection.setAutoCommit(true);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT assignmentID, deadline, lectureID FROM Assignment");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("assignment");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT instructorID, instructorName FROM Instructor");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("instructor");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT lectureID, lectureName, time, credit, instructorID FROM LectureStudent");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("lecture");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT lectureID, studentID FROM LectureStudent");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("lecture_student");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT resultID, grade FROM Result");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("result");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT studentID, studentName FROM Student");
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("student");
        can.displayTable(resultSet, numberOfColumns, metaData);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        // close the connection!
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

}//END main



public void displayTable(ResultSet resultSet, int numberOfColumns, ResultSetMetaData metaData) {

    try {
        for(int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++)
            System.out.printf("%-8s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
        System.out.println();

        while( resultSet.next () ) {

            for( int i=1 ; i<=numberOfColumns ; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));
            System.out.println();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) { }



}//END displayTable

}//END Can
```

It's working fine when it comes to creating tables. But the problem is that I get the following strange errors about syntax errors when I run the program.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1748)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1665)
at Can.main(Can.java:35)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, C@N.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis in the last Create statement: `PRIMARY KEY (resultID)");`

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. Why don't you isolate the problem to a single SQL query? You do by the way not have a problem with connecting, you have a problem with executing the SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in the last Create statement: `... PRIMARY KEY (resultID)");`

It should be:

```
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Results" + 
         "(resultID INT, grade FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY (resultID))");
                                                            ^
                                parenthesis added here -----|
```

Comment: Yeap. Silly me. I shouldn't write code when I'm sleepy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Throwing a hundred SQL statements into one big try-catch block doesn't help much.

Comment: Well it still pinpoints that line (line: 35) as the source of the problem... It's right there in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are putting '' in your ID field ... it's a INT type column. make your Insert query like

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES(1, 'instructorName1')");
```

your last create statement missing closing parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at line 35 as the error message says? If the lines are correct as you pasted them that is the last create Table statement? Something wrong with the SQL there.

Update: As pointed out in the comment to your question by @ypercube: you are missing a closing parenthesis there!